# Piping .NET Stream PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, stream

Is there a way to pipe a .NET stream in PowerShell?

Like

```
process {
  $stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
  $write = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream
  $stream | Out-String
  $write.Write("hello")
  $write.Flush()
}
```

Note the Write occurs after the the $stream is piped. Basically I'm trying to set up a way of getting a non-finished stream piped into the Output or Host stream as data comes into the stream.